# AMS1117 overheating due to short?

Tags: power-supply

I need some help with the below circuit (I know it is messy). The battery management circuit seems just fine but when I give power to the [ME2108](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2009081607_MICRONE-Nanjing-Micro-One-Elec-ME2188A27TG_C236831.pdf) and then to the [AMS1117](http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf) the AMS1117 will heat up very fast so I think I have a short somewhere.

Can you please give some quick ideas on what is going on? I did debugging for 2h but I'm not really an electrical engineer.

Thanks! :)

[image]

Comment: The GND connections in your schematic are a mess. You have wires looping back on themselves for no purpose, you appear to be relying on the ESP32 to connect different parts together, and I can't find any link between USB GND/-BATT and the GND(s) in the rest of the circuit.

Comment: Please check your pinout of the AMS1117 - I don't think you got your pins 1,2,3 connected correctly.

Comment: @brhans I know is a messy one, thing is it only heats up when I connect the esp32 other than that it does not. it bust be a connection issue

Comment: @td127 I think I got it right, VIN gets input 5v, ADJ goes filtered ground and then output

Comment: You've missed the point which @td127 is referring to. According to the AMS1117 datasheet, pin-1 is Gnd/ADJ, pin-2 is Vout, pin-3 is Vin. You have pins 1 & 2 swapped. You probably only see the fault when the ESP32 is connected because you're relying on the ESP32 to connect some of the various GND nets together in your circuit.

Comment: @brhans YES! that's why! dang it I can sleep better now. So I need to be careful with what design is the chip from jlpcb library hmm...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Vout of AMS1117 goes to VDD33 of the ESP32 WROVER module.

I guess that the ESP32 module has problems.

Comment: I just pulled the ESP32 out and tested it separately and it works ok

Comment: Inspect the board then. Find the other IC that is hot.

Comment: I think I will redesign everything. For the grounds, is ok to ground everything to the micro usb -v ?and then make the whole board grounded and leave only the traces with data or +v